# What happened to the Yin half of Kurama?

Tags: naruto

Did Naruto get both halves of Kurama after fighting Sasuke, or did the other half of Kurama die when Minato was killed?

Comment: He got the other Kurama.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After Madara receives his right eye from Zetsu, he stuns all the Tailed Beasts and began the process of sealing them up into the Demonic Statue. Yang Kurama, knowing that he will be pulled out of Naruto for certain, contacted Gaara to have Yin Kurama (within Minato's body) sealed into Naruto.

But just as Minato was transferring Yin Kurama into Naruto, Black Zetsu (in Obito's body) interferes.

Obito regains control of his body and prevents Zetsu from delivering the left Rinnegan eye and Yin Kurama to Madara. Obito then teleports the gang to Kamui dimension. There, Yin Kurama was successfully transferred into Naruto.

After the epic fight with Sasuke, Yang Kurama rejoins Naruto. The Yin and Yang halves merge together and formed the complete state of Kurama.

Comment: Where is the proof that yin and yang kuramas joined after fight with sasuke?

Comment: Where else would Yang Kurama go? Yin Kurama was already inside Naruto and both halves expressed their wish to stay with Naruto to the Sage of Six Paths. Sasuke let all the Tailed Beasts go, so Yang Kurama should have got back to Naruto.