# What happened to Yin Kurama inside Edo Minato after the war ended?

Tags: naruto, boruto

After Orochimaru reincarnated Namikaze Minato, Yondaime Hokage and the war ended. Does Yin Kurama still reside inside Minato even after he goes back to the heavens or did it return to Yang Kurama and now it is inside Naruto.

Can you please clarify this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happened to the Yin half of Kurama?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/30237/what-happened-to-the-yin-half-of-kurama)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minato's half on nine tails goes into naruto. In the end of the war, naruto gets the other half of the nine tails so he has both halves now.